# How did ancient Greek city-states secure mines to mint coins?

Tags: economy, ancient-greece, money

I have a basic question about mines and coinage.

I have read that different cities minted their own coins. The Athenians were lucky with the Laurion mines which contained silver. But what did cities do if there were no mines nearby?

Would they have to re-settle to a different place or did these cities have bad economies?

Comment: You can get precious metals by selling goods to cities and contries that do have precious metals. Not only bullion, melting down foreign coins to mint your own was very common until the popularization of bank notes.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that foreign coins were melted down too. I guess the purity of the newly minted coin was guaranteed by the city re-minting the coin?

Comment: Not sure about the specifics of the process. Also worth mentioning that typically coins from foreign entities would be accepted by many people (that is why in the New Testament appear money exchangers in the Temple); after all what mattered most was the guarantee of bullion that the coin had. It could even be the case that if those foreign coins were of better quality than the local ones, they would have been prefered as a means of exchange.

Comment: I don't know if you can call it a guarantee, but different currencies would have different "buying power" based on the credibility of the issuer. When ancient governments start debasing coins, people generally catch on quickly.

Comment: Purity of the coin was loosely guaranteed.  Debasement is the fiat era equivalent of inflation, and was common.  That is why different coins from different countries have different purchasing power

Comment: Ancient greece is a rather large time frame,  but the greek coins of that post-date alexanders conquests of asia were all mainly minted from the "Persian Mix" which was a massive hoard of silver,  around 5000 tons of it, that alexander brought back from asia. "Moreover, coin metal analyses have shown that, for both gold and silver, nearly all eastern production, as well as a substantial part of western production, notably in Macedonia, are likely to have been issued from this bullion, hereafter referred to as the “Persian mix”. - Oliver 2017 'Minted silver in the Empire of Alexander'